# JMeter JMS message authentication fails

Tags: java, jmeter, jms

I would like to send **JMS messages to my local JBoss 7.2 server**. For this purpose I tried using **JMeter** with the **JMS Point-to-Point** step. *I configured everything* as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

JNDI properties:

- java.naming.security.principal = ca2
- java.naming.security.credentials
  = 12346578

What I've tried on the server side:

- created an Application User (with the credentials in the JNDI properties)
- deleted security realm from `<http-connector name="http-remoting-connector"
  connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>`

The server is up and running, but *in both cases I got the following errors:*

Response message: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080 (Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:

DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication)] [Root exception is javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:

DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication]

What else should I try?

Comment: How is this related to Apache Camel? Have you have deployed jboss-client.jar lib to jmeter`s lib/ext folder? You can download get this jar from JBOSS_FOLDER/bin/client/jboss-client.jar

Comment: You are right, it is not necessarily related to Apache Camel, tag removed. The jboss-client.jar lib was a good hint, but now I get the following error:  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jboss -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jboss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out *my configuration was completely wrong*.

I apologize to everyone who tried to help me. It was a great lesson to learn for me.

Here is what I had to do, and you should consider if you are in a similar situation:

- **Remove jboss-client.jar** from jmeter's lib/ext folder. (It caused the connection to close too soon for some reason)
- Change JMeter Poin-to-Point step's Communication style to
  **request_only**
- Create a JBoss Application user **and add it to the guest group**
  (./add-user.sh -a --user ca2 --password 12345678 -g guest)
- **Activate the jboss profile** in server config (add the system property:
  `<property name="spring.profiles.active" value="jboss"/>`)
- And of course **configure the JMS consumer** properly in the Java code (one can check in the management console whether the consumer exists)

Thanks for everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

These `ca2` and `12346578` values don't look to be [MD5-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) to me, I think you need to use [UsernamePasswordHashUtil](https://github.com/wildfly-security/jboss-sasl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/sasl/util/UsernamePasswordHashUtil.java) in order to encrypt the credentials like

```
java -classpath /path/to/jboss/sasl/jar org/jboss/sasl/util/UsernamePasswordHashUtil <username> [realm name] <password>
```

Alternatively you can consider using [jboss-ejb-client](https://github.com/wildfly/jboss-ejb-client) and send your message programmatically from the [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language, something like:

```
def config = AuthenticationConfiguration.empty()
        .setSaslMechanismSelector(SaslMechanismSelector.NONE.addMechanism("DIGEST-MD5")).useName("ca2")
        .usePassword("12345678");
def ctx = AuthenticationContext.empty().with(MatchRule.ALL.matchHost("127.0.0.1"), config);
```